# SQL Server sum based on type

Tags: sql, sql-server

Titles:

```
Title        Type
Sample1      D+C-
Sample2      D+C-
Sample3      C+D-
Sample4      C+D-
```

The meaning of the type column are:
D+C- = Debit - Credit
C+D- = Credit - Debit

Transactions:

```
Type       Title       Amt
Debit      Sample1     200
Credit     Sample2     120
Debit      Sample1     110
Debit      Sample2     130
Credit     Sample3     150
Debit      Sample2     210
Debit      Sample3     250
Credit     Sample1     300
Credit     Sample4     220
```

I can sum per title but i can't compute based on the type of the title

```
SELECT
    title,
    SUM(amt) as amt
    type
FROM
    tbltran
GROUP BY
    title, type;
```

EDIT: I found another scenario that if there is only one credit transaction, thank you

The result must be:

```
Title       Amt
Sample1     10
Sample2     220
Sample3     -100
Sample4     220
```

Comment: I have no idea what the method is for the calculations.  What is the secret?  What do the types mean?

Comment: @TylerRoper I had the same thought, but it still doesn't make sense, at least it is not obvious.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, removed my comment there in the middle, but you're correct. `Sample3` would be `100` if debits were positive and credits were negative, as opposed to the `-100` OP has listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't entirely clear but I'm going to assume you're looking to return `title` and `amt`, where `amt` is the sum by title, the caveat being that debits and credits are either negative or positive according to the "Type" field in the "Titles" table.

Given your comment that there are only two types (`D+C-` and `C+D-`), we don't have to parse the query dynamically, but rather can just use some simple `CASE` logic.

Here are two options, either of which should work, however I don't have SQL Server available to me at the moment to compare them...

---

<sub><sub>**QUERY 1**</sub></sub>

```
SELECT
    t.title,
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN t.Type = 'Credit' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
      *
      CASE WHEN tc.Type = 'D+C-' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END
      *
      amt
    ) as amt
FROM
    tbltran t
    INNER JOIN tbltitles tc ON tc.Title = t.Title
GROUP BY
    t.title;
```

<sub><sub>**QUERY 2**</sub></sub>

```
SELECT
    t.title,
    SUM(
       CASE 
          WHEN t.Type = 'Credit' AND tc.Type = 'D+C-' THEN -amt
          WHEN t.Type = 'Credit' AND tc.Type = 'C+D-' THEN amt
          WHEN t.Type = 'Debit' AND tc.Type = 'D+C-' THEN amt
          WHEN t.Type = 'Debit' AND tc.Type = 'C+D-' THEN -amt
       END
    ) as amt
FROM
    tbltran t
    INNER JOIN tbltitles tc ON tc.Title = t.Title
GROUP BY
    t.title;
```

<sub><sub>**RESULT**</sub></sub>

```
title        amt
-----        ---
Sample1      10
Sample2      220
Sample3      -100
```

---

<sup>[**Query 1 SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fb90f/6)</sup>

<sup>[**Query 2 SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fb90f/5)</sup>

<sup>[**`CASE` Documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)</sup>

Comment: Close but i think we should inner join the title to transactions to get the 'type' column, for us to base the computation on that column, thanks

Comment: In the future, consider explaining all the details in your question instead of giving us a riddle. Also, if you're aware that the solution will need an inner join, why does the attempt you've shown not include one? Anyways... are `D+C-` and `C+D-` the only two possible types?

Comment: Sorry, yep those are the only types

Comment: Thank you it worked but i found one problem, if i have only one credit transaction, it result to negative, I've updated my question

Comment: I'm not understanding... that shouldn't be an issue in either of the queries I posted, I tested just to be sure: [Query 1 SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/25352/1) and [Query 2 SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/25352/2).

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, i made a mistake, on my database i though it's C+D-, your query is working, thank you very much.